# Using the letters of the word AGONIZE, how many four-letter code words can be formed with two vowels in two middle positions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm not the best at visualizing permutations. I'd appreciate if someone could help me with this question as well as explain the steps to do so.

Cannot use a letter more than once.
So far I've tried separating them into cases.

We have a case where the 2 consonants are used on the outside letters

7 * 4  * 3 * 4 = 336

We have a case where we start with a vowel or end with a vowel which is

7 * 3 * 2 * 4 = 168

Finally we have a case where only vowels are used

4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24 or 4!

The total would be 528 ways.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: An example of such a code word is GAIN; another example is AEIO.  What matters here is that the middle two positions be filled with vowels.  The first and last positions may be filled with any of the remaining letters once you fill the two middle positions with vowels.

Comment: Can you use a letter more than once? E.g., is AAAA an acceptable code word?

Comment: Cannot use a letter more than once. I believed that the question can be solved by separating them into groups similar to how you would if two letters had to be together. For example, it's a four-letter word that but there are three groups because two letters have to stick together, so we have 3!. I can't find anything else on the problem to compare answers with and I'm not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are seven distinct letters in the word AGONIZE, of which four are vowels.  We must ensure that there are vowels in the middle two positions.  Therefore, we will fill the middle two positions first, then fill the first and last positions.

There are four ways to place a vowel in the second position and three ways to place one of the remaining three vowels in the third position.  There are five ways to fill the first position with one of the remaining five letters and four ways to fill the last position with one of the remaining four letters.  Hence, there are
$$4 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 240$$
four-letter code words that can be formed from the letters of the word AGONIZE which have vowels in the middle two positions.

---

Let's correct your attempt.

*Two consonants are used as the outside letters*:  There are four vowels and three consonants in the word AGONIZE.  Thus, there are three ways to fill the first position with a consonant, four ways to fill the second position with a vowel, three ways to fill the third position with one of the remaining vowels, and two ways to fill the fourth position with one of the remaining consonants.  Hence, there are $$3 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 72$$ such code words.

*We start with a vowel or end with a vowel (but not both)*:  Suppose we start with a vowel.  There are four ways to fill the first position with a vowel, three ways to fill the second position with one of the three remaining vowels, two ways to fill the third position with one of the two remaining vowels, and three ways to fill the fourth position with one of the three consonants.  Hence, there are $$4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 72$$ code words which begin with a vowel but do not end with a vowel.

By symmetry, there are also $72$ code words which end with a vowel but do not begin with a vowel (interchange the roles of the first and last positions in the above argument.  Thus, there are $2 \cdot 72 = 144$ four-letter code words with exactly three vowels in which the middle two positions are filled with vowels.

*Only vowels are used*:  There are $4! = 24$ ways to fill the four positions with the four distinct vowels in the word AGONIZE.

**Total:** Since the three cases above are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of admissible code words is
$$3 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 + 4! = 72 + 144 + 24 = 240$$
as we found above.